# Route Prefix in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a controller called `BeconsController` that has a simple get Action. Using the route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

Routing is fine, with `http://locahost/beacons/5` (where 5 is the id) resolving to the correct action. However, I would like this to come under the 'api' path. I'd have thought this could be done by writing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

But I receives a 404 when pointing my browser at `http://locahost/api/beacons/5`. In fact, the old path still works, too: `http://locahost/beacons/5` takes me to to the page!

This should be simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also you can use attributes

    `[Route("api/[controller]")] public class CompetitionController : Controller`

Comment: Should you be using `UseMvc` with an `api` route? That route looks like a Web API route, and I wouldn't expect `UseMvc` to be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using only this route or do you have several routes in the routes object? If you have several it will take the first route that is matched to it.

Maybe the following links will help you:
http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfromwebapi2.html
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html?highlight=routes